# $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ : $\text{im } (f^{n + 1})\}\subsetneq \text{im } (f^n)$,iff $\ker (f^n) \subsetneq \ker (f^{n + 1})\}$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a $ \mathbb{R} $ -vector space, $ f \in \mathcal{L} ({V}) $. We know that:

- $ \{\ker (f^ n) \}_n $ is increasing in the sense of inclusion and if there is $n_0 \in \mathbb {N}$ such that $ \ker (f^n) = \ker (f^{n + 1}) $ then the sequence $ \{\ker (f^n) \}_n $ is stationary.
- $ \{\text{im }(f^n) \} $ is decreasing in the sense of inclusion and if there exists $ n_0 \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ \text{im } (f^n) = \text{im } (f^{n + 1}) $ then the sequence $ \{\text{im } (f^n) \}_n $ is stationary.

**Problem:**

Can we say that
$$
\forall n\in\mathbb{N}: \text{im } (f^{n + 1})\}\subsetneq \text{im } (f^n) \Leftrightarrow \forall n\in\mathbb{N}:\ker (f^n) \subsetneq \ker (f^{n + 1})\}$$
An idea please.

Comment: If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then yes. Otherwise no. Think "shift operators".

Comment: can you prove it please.